# Nginx proxy in Docker to Azure AKS with HTTPS

Tags: azure, docker, nginx

I have a web application running in Azure AKS. It has its own public DNS name and HTTPS configured.
But it has no authentication.

I want to authenticate users to access this application using built-in authentication feature of Azure App services and then proxy requests to my app in AKS.

I have installed a nginx_proxy in Docker and setup authentication. Authentication works, but in web browser I get 404 "No found" and does not reach application in AKS. Why?

The application itself is running fine and can be reached on its DNS name without proxy.

```
+----------------+                 +------------+
|  Azure         |                 | Azure AD   | Authnetication                   
|  Kubernetes    |                 +------------+                    
|  app           |                              
|  (my.aks.io)   |                 +-------------+                     
|                |                 | App Service |                     
|                |       404!      | Docker      |        200 ok             
|                |<-------https----| Nginx-proxy |<-------http-----
+----------------+   my.aks.io     +-------------+
```

My Nginx proxy config

```
server {
    listen  80;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://my.aks.io;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your visualization go from right to left, starting without https? Why do you start without https. Can you `curl https://my.aks.io` from within the Docker container?

Comment: I get same 404 Not found with HTTPS on Azure App Service. HTTPS is provided by App Service there.

Comment: It should be possible to reach my.aks.io from anywhere. It is public available. Not sure how to open shell there, since the container running in Azure App Service.

Comment: So the problem is not the Docker or nginx configuration. Your Azure app is not running properly. `https://my.aks.io/` is not a public available website either and `aks.io` doesn't appear to be your domain.

Comment: my.aks.io is just en example name of course, the real service is up and running with it's own real DNS name.

Comment: Use `example.com` as an example :-) So you should configure your Azure app properly then it should work.